# Restructure JSON format in React Native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I got a JSON data from an exchange rate API however when I tried to display it in `flatlist` i got an error: `Invariant violation tried to get frame for out of range index nan` then I realise that it is not the JSON format that I want. The data is :

```
{  
"rates":{  
  "CAD":0.1669423548,
  "HKD":1.0,
  "PLN":0.4835606816
},
"base":"EUR",
"date":"2019-07-11"
}
```

Which I want it looks like

```
{  
"rates":[  
  {  
     "currency":"hkd",
     "rate":"1",
     "base":"EUR",
     "date":"2019-07-11"
  },
     {  
     "currency":"CAD",
     "rate":"0.1669423548",
     "base":"EUR",
     "date":"2019-07-11"
  },
   {  
     "currency":"PLN",
     "rate":"0.4835606816",
     "base":"EUR",
     "date":"2019-07-11"
  },
]
}
```

This is how I fetch data

```
async _getRateData() {

const response = await fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=EUR');
const json = await response.json();

this.setState({
  loading: false,
  dataSource: json.base,
  rates: json.rates,
  date: json.date,
  base: json.base,
})
 }
```

I am new to react native and I have no clue how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your `_getRateData()` method to this:

```
async _getRateData() {

  const response = await fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=EUR');
  const json = await response.json();

  // setting up data object from API endpoint to work with
  const data = {
    rates: json.rates,
    date: json.date,
    base: json.base,
  }

  // data transformation
  const newData = {
    // Object.keys method return array of all keys in rates obejct
    rates: Object.keys(data.rates).map((currency, idx) => {
      // then with map function you can map all keys
      // and construct your own data structure
      return {
        currency, // first element currency (the same as currency: currency, es6 shortcode)
        rate: data.rates[currency], // accessing rates element by key
        base: data.base, // adding rest of the data
        date: data.date
      };
    })
  };

  // setting data to state
  this.setState({
    loading: false,
    dataSource: json.base,
    rates: newData.rates // set to rates only array
  })

}
```

Demo with simple data: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-carson-d5idp

Comment: We typically don't write code for posters, we fix their code. Teach them to fish. At least, give it some explanation

Comment: @Janiis Thanks your code is clear which makes me easy to learn but add some explanation would be great!

Comment: @Rachellllls added comments to the code, for you to better understand how this works.